# How can i enable Auto Import in Android Studio 1.2x

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I am gradually moving from Eclipse to Android Studio & i'm having a hard time trying to figure out Android Studio short cuts.

How can i enable Auto Import in Android Studio 1.2.1.1 on a Windows PC, to automatically suggest classes to import. just like Eclipse does.

From my research i found out It used to be in Settings -> Editor -> Auto Import. on a Windows PC

But i cannot find that in this recent version.

Comment: AS highlights the un-imported class with red, press Alt+Enter to import it, Ctrl+Alt+L organizes code, unsure if it organizes imports too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set Android Studio Auto import in Android Studio 1.2x From

`File->Setting->Editor->General->Auto Import`

Change `Insert imports on paste` to `All` ,

set `Add unambiguous imports on the fly` and `optimize imports on the fly` as checked.

Comment: Yes @AliSh , thanks for your answer, but it seems to me that except from Auto import, Android Studio doesn't provide Quick fix like Eclipse. or does it ?

Comment: @HtmlTosin: No, there isn't anything same quick fix in Eclipse, but Alt+Enter work like Quick fix of Eclipse, if you enable Auto Import, it's really reduce your need to quick fix.

Comment: Yea true, noticed that 2 days ago !

Answer (score 4):

Some important shortcuts you may need everyday:

**Add unimplemented methods:**   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

**Override methods:** <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

**Format code:**  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

**Show project:** <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>

**Show logcat:** <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd>

**Hide project - logcat:** <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd>

**Build:** <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd>

**Build and Run:**  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>

**Collapse all:** <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>NumPad +</kbd>

**Expand all:** <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>NumPad -</kbd>

**Find and replace:** <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

**Find:** <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Or you can print a copy of it and keep on your desk or you can make wallpaper of this Awesome Collection of Shortcuts!  [Download Shortcuts](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the shortcuts, i appreciate